Equilibrium of Forces on a triangle
3 forces P,Q & R are acting along BC, CA and AB sides of a triangle such that it is in equilibrium. Prove that $$\frac{1+\cos A}P +\frac{1+\cos B}Q + \frac{1+\cos C}R=0$$

Show your workings please, and don’t forget to type your equations using latex: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

I would have thought that taking moments about A, for instance, shows that P must be zero, as the lines of action of Q and R pass through A, and the line of action of P doesn't.
